# Why does sleep not wait, no matter how high the value entered in the parentheses is?

Tags: c++, sleep

I'm trying to rewrite a program that I have written earlier in C++ that connects to my laptop over ssh or sftp based on what the user types, that program works fine but I am trying to write the std::cout out letter by letter with a 200ms delay in between characters.
Here's my current attempt(doesn't work):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
std::cout << "S";
sleep(0.2);
std::cout << "S";
sleep(0.2);
std::cout << "H";
sleep(0.2);
std::cout << " o";
sleep(0.2);
std::cout << "r";
sleep(0.2);
std::cout << " S";
sleep(0.2);
std::cout << "F";
sleep(0.2);
std::cout << "T";
sleep(0.2);
std::cout << "P";
std::cout << "?\n" << ">"; 

std::string contype;
std::cin >> contype;
if(contype == "ssh")
{
system("ssh redacted");
}
if(contype == "sftp")
{
system("sftp redacted");
}
}
```

Comment: `sleep` functions usually expect an integer argument. `0.2` converted to an integer is `0`. If this is POSIX's `sleep` function, there is a `usleep` version for microsecond sleed. But you should use the portable [`std::this_thread::sleep_for`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for) instead of platform specific sleep functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using c++11, you should use thread and chrono to sleep for 200ms.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

int main()
{
std::cout << "S" << std::flush;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(200));
    std::cout << "S" << std::flush;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(200));
    std::cout << "H" << std::flush;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(200));
    std::cout << " o" << std::flush;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(200));
    std::cout << "r" << std::flush;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(200));
    std::cout << " S" << std::flush;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(200));
    std::cout << "F" << std::flush;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(200));
    std::cout << "T" << std::flush;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(200));
    std::cout << "P" << std::flush;
    std::cout << "?\n" << ">";

std::string contype;
std::cin >> contype;
if(contype == "ssh")
{
system("ssh redacted");
}
if(contype == "sftp")
{
system("sftp redacted");
}
}
```

should work just fine.
Edit: you should output std::flush at the end of each output to explicitly flush the buffer.

Edit 2: as mentioned in the comments, defining a constant instead of using the magic number upon every iteration is better. Another option is to define a function that goes over a string and prints each letter, then waits. This would like this -

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

void printAndSleep(const std::string& msg, int timePeriod);

int main()
{
    const std::string msg = "SSH or SFTP";
    const int waitingTime = 200;
    printAndSleep(msg, waitingTime);
    std::cout << "?\n" << ">";

std::string contype;
std::cin >> contype;
if(contype == "ssh")
{
system("ssh redacted");
}
if(contype == "sftp")
{
system("sftp redacted");
}
}

void printAndSleep(const std::string& msg, int timePeriod){
    for (char c : msg) {
        std::cout << c << std::flush;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(timePeriod));
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know if this is an issue with me, my pc or the compiler, but this just waits for the total sum of all the sleep statements in the beginning and executes everything else at once after.

Comment: @cheeselover69 `std::cout` doesn't implicitly flush on sleep. Use `<< std::flush` before each sleep like `std::cout << "r" << std::flush` to force the output to be pushed to the output device.

Comment: This answer would be improved by using a constant instead of repeating the magic number every other line.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux thanks! that worked